# are OEM preinstalled Android Apps automatically updated by Play store?

Tags: android, google-play, versioning

It looks like an Android device hardware vendor will be shipping a new device with our App pre-installed. Today, we hand to our customer an APK and they publish it to the Play store. In the future, that same App will come pre-installed on this new device.

I don't know how they build their Android image or how they will include our App in that image (sorry, I haven't gotten that info yet).

If the App is pre-installed by the hardware vendor, and later we publish an update for the App to the Play store, will users of the pre-installed app be notified that an update is available through the standard Play Store/Android [versioning mechanisms](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)?

Do we have to do anything special to allow the pre-installed app to be updated from the Play store?

Comment: Were you able to get any idea how do they install the app to Android Os?

Comment: That project got cancelled before we ever really got to work with the hardware vendor. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 6):

It seems as though this should happen automatically when your application is pushed to Google Play, as long as it follows some guidelines set by Google. See here:

> **Updating system apps**
>
> The user’s system apps (including any pre-loaded apps) are shown in the My Apps section of the user's device in the Google Play store as soon as an application with the same package name is uploaded to the Google Play Developer Console, even if the application is unpublished.
>
> Google Play can manage updates to preloaded applications, provided the following conditions are met:
>
> - The preloaded app needs to be in the system partition
> - The preloaded app needs to be free
> - The preloaded app needs to be signed with the same signature as the app published in Google Play
> - The Package Name of the preloaded and updated app needs to be the same
> - The Version Code of the updated app needs to be greater than that of the preloaded app
>
> If you need to upload a system application and encounter an error message when doing so, please contact us.

[Source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks! Today, I've got a first meeting to discuss with the vendor packaging the apps. This link is a great help.

Comment: I tested this check list. I made a version of my APK with a versionCode lower than the version in the play store. I did a factory reset on my phone and rooted the phone. I went through setup without setting up networking or a Google account. I used ADB to install my test APK to /system/app folder (on Android 4.2.2). I enabled Wifi and set up a Google account. I ran the play store app and installed a different application. My test App is not auto-updated and I do not receive notification that an upgrade is available.I can use the Play Store to update my App, but I do not get a notification.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the fact that the application wasn't built into the system when Android was built, but instead was sideloaded into the `/system/app/` folder. I'm no expert, just something to consider.

Comment: Yes, I think real OEM system install is different than what I did. But, this is the closest I could come to testing the checklist.